# Evaluate $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} -\Delta\Phi(x) dx$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

For my PDE class I again have to do things with which I am not overly familiar. This time I have to integrate the negative laplacian of the so-called regularised fundamental solution of the laplace equation over the whole real $n$-dimensional space, that is

$$ \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} -\Delta \Phi(x) dx$$

To put it precisely, the **question** is how to evaluate

$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} -\Delta \Phi(x) dx = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\alpha(n)}(\lvert x\rvert^2 + 1)^{\frac{-n-2}{2}}\lvert x\rvert^2 + (\lvert x\rvert^2 + 1)^{-n/2}) dx$$

where obviously $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but I am not sure how to tackle the integral. What I **tried** was to use some analysis theorem which tells me that I can identify $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$ with $(0,\infty) \times \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ but then I didn't know how to integrate over $\mathbb{S^{n-1}}$ next which made me think whether this is the appropriate approach at all. Is there some general idea or guideline behind these kinds of $\mathbb{R}^n$-integrals?

Comment: Well it's spherically symmetric, so changing to spherical coordinates should immediately reduce it to a single-variable integral on $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Although I know how to switch to polar or cylindrical coordinates I am not sure how to do the transformation to n-dimensional spherical coordinates. What I know is that you several trigonometric functions after the transformation, including a lot of sines. But I do not know what to do with this integral form, I only saw spherical coordinates with very easy examples.

Comment: Since there's no angular dependence, you don't have to worry about the angular coordinates - you can just write $\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(r) dx = \int_0^\infty f(r) s_n r^{n-1} dr$ where $s_n$ is the hyperarea of the unit $(n-1)$-sphere.

Comment: Thank you, Anthony Carapetis. This was very helpful! One last question: Is the hyperarea of the unit $(n-1)$-sphere its surface or volume? I have found formulas for both. Also, I encourage you to write your hints as answer so that I can upvote and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integrand is a function of the radial coordinate $r = |x|$, changing to (hyper)spherical coordinates reduces it to a single-variable integral. Explicitly,

$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(|x|) dx = s_n \int_0^\infty f(r) r^{n-1} dr$$

where $s_n = 2 \pi^{n/2}/\Gamma(n/2)$ is the surface hyperarea of the unit $(n-1)$-sphere.